# A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. with Linq Any()

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach, ef-core-2.1

I am trying to speed up my code so I want to see how much faster my code can go if I do async.

The problem is that in my parallel loop I have to do some checks and right now I was doing lazy loading which I think it causing the error

```
A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed.
```

Right now I have schema like this

```
TableATableB - many to many column
TableA - Can have many TableBs 
TableB - Can have many TableAs
TableC - TableB can have many TableCs and TableC can only have 1 tableB
```

Now the problem where my code is dieing is when I do

```
foundTableBColumn.TableCs.Any()
```

I tried to do eager loading but I get the same issue

```
var foundTableBs = dbContext.TableATableB Include(x => x.TableB).ThenInclude(x => x.TableC).Where(x => x.TableAId == 1).Select(x => x.TableA).ToList();


Parallel.ForEach(foundTableBs , (tableB, loopState) =>
                {
                      if(tableB.TableCs.Any(){
}
                });
```

Comment: EF doesn't support more than one simultaneous async operation on a single context instance.

Comment: then how do I get around that so I can do this more async?

Comment: You can still use regular ADO.Net. Or you could create multiple db contexts but I don't think that's a good idea.

Comment: why is my includes do not seem to work? I was hoping if I loaded everything up i memory that would get around it. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know.

Comment: Ok, I guess I will try to use ado.net I do want to map it to some objects though but I don't know how to make TableB  have a collection of TabeC .